# "Uncaught TypeError: Property 'touchLayer' of object function ( selector, context )" when using afui and jquery on phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, appframework

I'm using phonegap for deploying a web application made in afui (Intel Appframework UI) for Android, but, when I test it in the android emulator the debug console shows me the following error after I have just started the app:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'touchLayer' of object function (selector, context) 
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced' 
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery ); 
} is not a function at file:///android_asset/www/ui/appframework.ui.js:3281
```

And all the javascript functionality is disabled.

I can't figure out what is the problem. I have tested the app in chrome over Elementary OS and it works fine.

I'm using phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0, jQuery 1.10.2, and App Framework UI 2.0.

I'm importing the js files in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/jq.appframework.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="ui/appframework.ui.js"></script>
```

I hope somebody can help me to find a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same problem. Eventually, looking at the index.html in the Appframework Kitchen Sink, I found out that to make the error disappear you need the following script inside the app index.html:

```
var webRoot = "./";
$.ui.autoLaunch = false; //By default, it is set to true and you're app will run right away.  We set it to false to show a splashscreen
/* This function runs when the body is loaded.*/
var init = function () {
        $.ui.backButtonText = "Back";// We override the back button text to always say "Back"
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            $.ui.launch();
        }, 1500);//We wait 1.5 seconds to call $.ui.launch after DOMContentLoaded fires
    };
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
$.ui.ready(function () {
    //This function will get executed when $.ui.launch has completed
});
```

I don't know yet why this code is needed, but its use is also documented [here](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui-quickstart).

Comment: There apparently is/was a race condition of when the touchlayer was initialized and used in launch, if you didn't set the application to have a delayed start. So in the code above, the 1.5 second wait until launch allowed the initializations to finish.
See https://github.com/01org/appframework/issues/548

Comment: I had changed the value of $.ui.autoLaunch to true in my code, I just turned it back to false and now it works, thanks;